# Python print function not rendering graph

Tags: python, ubuntu, plot, graph, printing

When I run the below code, no graph is printed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dark_IV = pd.read_csv("~/projects/IV/IVdata/DarkIVPractice.csv")
data = dark_IV.loc[:,["Dark IV:V","Dark IV:I"]]
x=dark_IV["Dark IV:V"]
y=dark_IV["Dark IV:I"]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.grid(True)
plt.gca().xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show(block= False)
```

**Sample Code**

```
Dark IV:Time    Dark IV:V   Dark IV:Time_1  Dark IV:I
0                0.678102         0          -9.865
0.00085          0.678016      0.00085       -9.831
0.0017           0.677672      0.0017        -9.74
0.00255          0.677095      0.00255       -9.599
0.0034           0.676312      0.0034        -9.413
0.00425          0.67534       0.00425       -9.188
0.0051           0.674213      0.0051        -8.932
.....            .....         .....         .....
```

I am currently using Ubuntu.  Is there an add-on that I need so that a graph can be rendered?

Comment: try `x=dark_IV["Dark IV:V"].values.tolist()`

`y=dark_IV["Dark IV:I"].values.tolist()`

Comment: Are you getting any error?If yes, please share the error logs. Also, can you provide a sample of the csv you are trying to read?

Comment: There is no error.  

The CSV  has 5 columns and about 800 rows.  The two columns I need are the ones that I chose (as seen in code).

Comment: The suggestions @pyd made did not make a difference.  There is still no output.  No error.  Nothing printed.

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: in jupyter you would want to add this line:  %matplotlib inline

Comment: Sample data is provided @pyd

Comment: can you try with someother editor

Comment: Does Ubuntu require an addition piece of software to render a graph?  I've already tried it on Git Bash as well.  It produces the same results- nothing.